# Variable Number of Input Fields in Classic-ASP form

Tags: asp-classic

I have a check out form where number of products can be "n". So how i can know how many input fields are in the form and take input from it?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's a group of single controls - say a variable number of checkboxes representing items - the solution is pretty straightforward.  For your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ProductID" value="1" />Product #1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ProductID" value="2" />Product #2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ProductID" value="3" />Product #3
```

Then in your ASP, you could do this:

```
<%
  Dim intID

  For Each intID In Request.Form("ProductID")
    ' intID now represents a selected product ID.  Insert into DB
    ' or whatever your process is.  Note that only the "checked" values
    ' will be passed to the server.
  Next
%>
```

In fact, this approach will work for any number of controls with the same name.  If it were 1 - n number of textboxes with the name "FavoriteColor", you could `For Each` through each value in the same manner.  Textboxes with no user input would not be passed.

Now, if your checkout form contains a group of input controls per item, you can build on that approach by carefully naming your other controls:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="ProductID" value="1" />Product #1<br />
<input type="textbox" name="Product1_Quantity">
<input type="textbox" name="Product1_Color">
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="ProductID" value="2" />Product #2<br />
<input type="textbox" name="Product2_Quantity">
<input type="textbox" name="Product2_Color">
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="ProductID" value="3" />Product #3
<input type="textbox" name="Product3_Quantity">
<input type="textbox" name="Product3_Color">
</div>
```

Now, again, on the server you could parse the data in this way:

```
<%
  Dim intID
  Dim intQuantity
  Dim strColor

  For Each intID In Request.Form("ProductID")
    ' this is a selected item
    intQuantity = Request.Form("Product" & intID & "_Quantity")
    strColor = Request.Form("Product" & intID & "_Color")
  Next
%>
```

You'd be able to perform validation and other logic on each group of selected items in this manner.