# ASP classic, post row data and grouping rows into id

Tags: forms, post, asp-classic

I have the following html table:

```
ID | a      | b      | c
------------------------------
1  | valuea | valueb | valuec
2  | valuea | valueb | valuec
```

Each column has an input box for the value (apart from the id)

```
<input name = "1_a" value = "valuea" />
<input name = "1_b" value = "valueb" />
<input name = "1_c" value = "valuec" />

<input name = "2_a" value = "valuea" />
<input name = "2_b" value = "valueb" />
<input name = "2_c" value = "valuec" />
```

I'm submitting this to an asp classic page that will update each row with its property in the sql table.

At the moment, I need to split the name string at 1"_"a to get the correct row(1,2) and property(a,b,c)...
Is there a better way of doing this?

something along the lines of:

```
<input name = "2[a]" />
```

then in my asp classic I would have an array of all the post data like so:

```
[1] =>
    "a" => "valuea"
    "b" => "valueb"
    "c" => "valuec"
[2] =>
    "a" => "valuea"
    "b" => "valueb"
    "c" => "valuec"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp classic, if there is more than one input with the same name, it will return it in an array like string structure.  Maybe you can use this kind of grouping.

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839227/variable-number-of-input-fields-in-classic-asp-form)