# Classic ASP add multiple rows to database

Tags: asp-classic

Hi I'm using the following code to add data into a database and i need to be able to add several lines into the database at the same time. The lines will insert into the same DB but will have different values. Please see code below;

```
    <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="../Connections/Conn02.asp" -->
<%
Dim MM_editAction
MM_editAction = CStr(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
If (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
  MM_editAction = MM_editAction & "?" & Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString)
End If

' boolean to abort record edit
Dim MM_abortEdit
MM_abortEdit = false
%>
<%
If (CStr(Request("MM_insert")) = "form1") Then
  If (Not MM_abortEdit) Then
    ' execute the insert
    Dim MM_editCmd

    Set MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_Conn02_STRING
    MM_editCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mydatabase.test (name) VALUES (?)" 
    MM_editCmd.Prepared = true
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 201, 1, -1, Request.Form("namex")) ' adLongVarChar
    MM_editCmd.Execute
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close
  End If
End If
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form ACTION="<%=MM_editAction%>" METHOD="POST" name="form1">
<input type="text" name="namex">
<input type="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

can i make this loop through a form where a user may have entered several values for the field name?

This is just an example im trying to work out.

Comment: if this is classic ASP, then why did you tag it as ASP.NET?

Comment: it says asp-classic on my page?

Comment: Ah, someone else tagged it ASP.NET, then a 3rd person came along and tagged it correctly.

Comment: Must have!.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do this. For this, you should search  "classic asp dynamic form" topic

May this link can help you. If I were your in your shoes, I prefer to learn Asp.Net. Classic Asp to old :( . I stop to work this lang. around 2011.

[Variable Number of Input Fields in Classic-ASP form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839227/variable-number-of-input-fields-in-classic-asp-form)

https://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/701049-dynamic-variable-array-asp-form-text-input

Comment: If this help you, please  tick the answer ☺

Comment: why did you give me negative vote? I think this is usefull...
I want to se, where I am missing